# check either startdate or end date is in last week

Tags: mysql, sql

I want  to check either startdate or enddate is in last week.I want to display the rows which has commRunStart or commRunEnd date is in last week .

```
 SELECT A.commRunStart, A.commRunEnd FROM  `commRuns` AS A
 WHERE A.commRunStart >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) +6 DAY
    OR A.commRunEnd < CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) -1 DAY
```

Comment: What do you mean by "last week?  This is not particularly well-defined.  Examples would help explain.

Comment: What if the start date is before last week, and the end date is after last week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT A.commRunStart, A.commRunEnd FROM  `commRuns` AS A
 WHERE (A.commRunStart >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) +6 DAY
    AND A.commRunStart < CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) -1 DAY )
    OR (A.commRunEnd >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) +6 DAY
    AND A.commRunEnd < CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) -1 DAY )
```

Comment: What happens at the end of the year / beginning of a new year?